# finagle filter add default behavior

Tags: scala, finagle, twitter-finagle

question about filter : https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/finagle.html#Filter

For typical stack of filters + service layout, how can I add a default behavior for each of the filters? Which basically look at the request/response and do some side effect actions(counting, logging etc). I don't want to write code for each filter, but rather want to have this default behavior triggered on end of each filter.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is filter composition, i.e. you create a filter that's really just a pass-through and causes some side-effects and then you can mix that in with any other filter via composition. e.g.:

```
val authFilter: Filter[HttpReq, HttpRep, AuthHttpReq, HttpRep]
val loggingFilter[Req, Rep]: Filter[Req, Rep, Req, Rep]

val authWithLogging: Filter[HttpReq, HttpRep, AuthHttpReq, HttpRep] =
  authFilter andThen loggingFilter
```

Comment: that can work, but it will be strange, say I have:
FilterA andThen
FilterB andThen
FilterC 

with this approach I will be doing :
FilterA andThen
LoggingFilter andThen
FilterB andThen 
LoggingFilter andThen
FilterC

Comment: Correct. That's why LoggingFilter should be composed in rather than say, be a common filter base class. Ideally you would compose the filters you need for the service you need rather than compose previously composed filters